# Android Development! Не могу импортировать три класса: DefaultHttpClient, HttpGet, ResponseHandler. Работаю в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, веб-сервер, mobile-development

Не могу импортировать **DefaultHttpClient**, **HttpGet**, **ResponseHandler**. При создании объектов этих классов подчеркивает красным и просит создать их, **про import ни слова**. В манифесте прописал `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` и `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`. Не помогло.

Comment: Ну а, собственно, прописать импорты вы пробовали?..

Comment: Конечно. Написал import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet; и студия подчеркнула мне HttpGet и предложила найти JAR on Web. В последствии предлагает мне выбрать JAR File которого у меня нет и где взять не знаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Они объявлены `deprecated` начиная с 19 апи, и убраны из стандартного Андроид СДК начиная с 23 Апи.

Используйте `HttpURLConnection` или спец библиотеки для интернет запросов, например `Retrofit` или https://github.com/turbomanage/basic-http-client

UPD. Не рекомендуется, но все же если очень хочется продолжать использовать `DefaultHttpClient` и компанию то добавьте в градл:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

См. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client